# iterating over a sublist in python

Tags: python, list, iterator

Say I have the following list:

```
my_list = [2, 3, 4, 1, 44, 222, 43, 22]
```

How can I assign a constant value to all the elements in a sublist without the use of for loop? something like:

```
my_list[0:5:1] = 1 # Assign 1 to first 5 elements. This code is wrong since list requires an iterator
```

Specifically, I would like to assign a constant value to all the elements, starting from an index, `i` till the `end` of the list i.e. say

```
my_list[i:end] = 1 # What I would like to do. The code itself is wrong
```

Any suggestions on how to do it in the cleanest way in python?

Comment: If you're doing this a lot, you might find [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) interesting.

Comment: @BrendanLong: indeed it is. It's just that I have observed that although numpy is very fast, but the associated overhead of converting list to numpy array can quickly become a bottleneck, specially when I have around 10^8 elements to del with. But maybe I am wrong. your views ?

Comment: I definitely wouldn't convert between numpy arrays and lists all the time. Whether it's useful depends on your situation; I just thought it was interesting that Numpy has pretty much exactly the feature you were asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
my_list[i:end] = [1]*(end-i)
```

Examples:

```
>>> def test(my_list, i, end):
...     my_list[i:end] = [1]*(end-i)
...     return my_list
>>> test(range(10), 0, 5)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> test(range(10), 5, 10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> test(range(10), 3, 8)
[0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes a 2-liner is better than a 1-liner.

```
for i in range(0,5):
    my_list[i] = 0
```

If you really want to make something obfuscated:

Here's a one-liner which does the job without changing the original array.

```
new_list = [0 if i in range(0,5) else x for x, i in zip(my_list, xrange(len(my_list)))]
```

Which would you rather come across in unknown code? Or your own code 6 months later.

Comment: Yep. I'm specifically saying "it's not worth it, this reads well and does the job".

Comment: The reason I said without the use of for loop was, my code kind of already has some nested `for` so I wanted to avoid it. Therefore I was looking for something probably by slicing, but not sure how. But I do get your point

Comment: Why is that a reason to avoid it? Nested `for` are normal. Code has to be made of something!

Comment: @Levon of course, I agree. But there are so many questions on here that have mistaken assumptions, I tend to try and answer the original question unless the OP gives a reason why not in their qu.

Comment: I do agree. I am under the impression that maybe using `for` loop will have extra plenty on speed as compared to using something similar to what @minitech and @F.J have mentioned. your views ?

Comment: Can the last one not just be written, `newlist = [0 if i in set(range(0, 5, 1)) else i for i in oldlist]`?

Comment: @JonClements - the second one wasn't an entirely serious answer. I was just contrasting one-liners-for-the-sake-of-one-liners with the first example.

Comment: I kind of guessed that, but still :)

Comment: @R.Bahl - all of these answers will involve a `for` loop somewhere. It's how computers work. The only real way to know is to profile it and measure how different solutions perform, especially with a highly dynamic language like Python.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is `stuff [0:5] = [1] * 5`.  However, you should be cautious since this will change the size of the list if you get the number of replacing elements wrong.  If you do `stuff [0:5] = [1] * 6`, you will increase the size of the list (i.e., putting six 1s where there used to be five original values).

Comment: Had to run this myself before I actually believed it would work, but it does. Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work:

```
my_list = my_list[:i] + [1 for x in xrange(len(my_list) - i)]
```

Answer (score 1):

For going to the end of the list, just omit the end of the slice. Then, you can repeat a list to assign to it:

```
my_list[i:] = [1] * (len(my_list) - i)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
from itertools import repeat

my_list[start:end] = repeat( 1, end - start )
```

Comment: How are start and end defined?

Comment: They're just variables defining the range, no different from the usage of i/end in most of the other examples given here, I just thought start/end was a little more consistent and clear than i/end.